# why these two dashes (-) are different in USER-AGENT

Tags: c#, string

1 USER-AGENT

2 USER-AGENT

1 and 2 are different when you compare it. I suspect the dash is somehow different, but I don't know why (online diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/uRuANqCI)

Comment: The text originally posted had a hidden BOM `U+FEFF` before the first `U`, which then got lost in OP's subsequent edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side of your diff starts with a [`ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). The remainder of the strings are identical. Especially those dash characters are the same.

Comment: thanks, btw how did you find the hidden BOM?

Comment: @souserk You can copy the text and paste it in an environment where you can look at characters individually, e.g. a hex editor or a programming language where you can split strings up by character.